# codeigniter direct file access

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a clean install of codeigniter running. I need to access a library file diretly, but i get Access forbidden all the time. Is there any way to fix this? can't find anything about this in the config files etc.

Comment: Why do you need to access the library files directly!! CI is designed to not allow access to the library files from outside the application. You should use Loader class instead to load any library.

Answer (score 1):

you should try using the codeigniter [loader class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html), if i'm understanding the full question here, example below:

```
$this->load->library('email');
```